# Python Syntax error while execution

Tags: python

I am getting a syntax error for the line below i am not sure why this error is getting generated as earlier it used to work fine and suddenly it started throwing this error

```
myfile.write('\n'+str(serverAndInstance)+','+str(GCOverHead)+','+str(min(usedAfterGc))+','+str(max(usedAfterGc))+','+str(sum(usedAfterGc)/len(usedAfterGc))+',0,0')
```

Comment: Your formatting is borked, try using the "{}" button in the editor to get it looking like code that we can read.

Comment: Show the code that precedes this line as well. It could be due to a stray (unclosed) triple-quote or parenthesis that starts before this line, for example.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: no the line, as *edited*, has a syntax error. If you look at the original post by MatjuJain, you'll see there is a `/` between the `sum` and the `len`.

Comment: @unutbu: Yup, BSH also pointed this out to me; I restored the original line (with code formatting).

Comment: @rjv: **Please** pay attention when 'improving' formatting. [This edit](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/4385056) introduced a syntax error as the `/` operator was deleted. The suggested edit reviewers are at fault for approving the edit as well here.

Answer (score 0):

Your line, as posted, works just fine, which means that the **preceding line** is missing a closing `)`, `]` or `}` parenthesis, bracket or brace:

```
>>> something = (something_else + str(whatever)
... myfile.write('\n'+str(serverAndInstance)+','+str(GCOverHead)+','+str(min(usedAfterGc))+','+str(max(usedAfterGc))+','+str(sum(usedAfterGc)/len(usedAfterGc))+',0,0')
  File "<stdin>", line 2
    myfile.write('\n'+str(serverAndInstance)+','+str(GCOverHead)+','+str(min(usedAfterGc))+','+str(max(usedAfterGc))+','+str(sum(usedAfterGc)/len(usedAfterGc))+',0,0')
         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Here it is the `something` line that is missing a closing parenthesis (2 times `(` but only one `)`) but Python won't know it is missing until parsing the next line.

You really should use the [`csv` module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) instead to write comma-separated values to a file, your line would be a lot more readable if you used:

```
with open(outputfile, 'wb') as outfh:
    csvwriter = csv.writer(outfh)
    for something in some_iterable:
        # ...

        row = [serverAndInstance, GCOverHead, min(usedAfterGc), max(usedAfterGc), 
               sum(usedAfterGc) / len(usedAfterGc), 0, 0]
        csvwriter.writerow(row)
```